# Performance of Oracle's dbms_crypto.hash function for SHA-1

Tags: performance, oracle, hash, sha1

Looking for stats for input sizes of at least between 4 and 30 MB.

Comment: Performance of such a hash algorithm is going to be extremely system dependent.  Why not just create a simple program with some test data to get the performance numbers on your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no published stats, but as Gandalf suggested in the comment on your question, you can test it yourself.  To get the stats I would recommend using the DBMS_PROFILER package which times lines of PLSQL down to the nanosecond.

A quick primer on DBMS_PROFILER cribbed from Oracle PL/SQL Programming by Steven Feuerstein (published by O'Reilly):

Install scripts (for your DBA): $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/profload.sql

Install scripts (for your schema to capture stats): $ORACLE_HOME/rdmbs/admin/proftab.sql

scripts for reporting (for your schema): $ORACLE_HOME/plsql/demo/profrep.sql
                                         $ORACLE_HOME/plsql/demo/profsum.sql

to profile:

```
Begin
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_PROFILER.START_PROFILER('tag value for your run'));
   your_procedure_to_test();
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_PROFILER.STOP_PROFILER());
END;
```

to get reports, run one of the queries in the scripts for reporting.